# CUDA order of block execution in single kernel launch

Tags: cuda

I'm launching 256 threads in total. When I do it by launching a single block, everything works fine. But when I launch the threads in 2x2 blocks each with (8x8 threads), the kernel loops infinitely. Well, the real problem is that my kernel code waits for partial results from other blocks and after running several tests, I observed that the blocks were launched in a random order and they seem to be executed in a sequential order.

Do CUDA blocks run in parallel if they're launched from the same kernel? The GPU I'm using is not a limitation since I'm launching only 256 threads and a GTX 580 can handle them. (everything works fine in a single block launch of 16x16 threads)
Is there a way I can know the order of execution or maybe specify it?

Comment: With only a grid of 4 blocks total, there's no reason that all 4 blocks would not begin executing more or less simultaneously, on 4 different SMs in a GTX 580.  You've given no real details about your code nor any description of how you "observed that the blocks ... seem to be executed in a sequential order."  There is no ability at this time in the GPU to know a priori the order of execution of blocks or to specify the order of execution of blocks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, blocks run in parallel. How many blocks are run in parallel is determined by performance of your GPU, but important thing is that launching order of blocks is **undefined** and **indefinable**. Read more [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/pdf/CUDA_C_Programming_Guide.pdf) - chapter 2.2, last three paragraphs.

Comment: Link to source would be nice

Comment: But they aren't running parallelly in my case. Blocks are running only after other blocks have finished execution. Do I have to enable something for parallel execution? Random order is fine with me as long as they're parallel.

Comment: @tecfreak: I don't fully get what you are trying to ask. So further explanation: As long as GPU has free resources (not fully occupied streaming multiprocessors(SM) ) one of non-executed blocks is picked and launched on certain SM and will reside there until all threads within that block have finished.

Comment: @tecfreak blocks are assigned to a SM for execution only if the SM has enough resources left to accommodate the block. If you have overall more blocks than can fit onto all of the SMs combined, it is clear that some blocks have to wait for others to finish before they can be assigned to a SM.

Comment: Okay I get it, there aren't enough free resources. Guess I have to change the way I'm coding to reduce inter-dependencies.